# jQuery click on table cell event

Tags: jquery, html-table, cell

I have a html code like below

```
<tbody>
  <tr id="info">
    <td class="name">Joe</td>
    <td class="surname">White</td>
    <td class="age">25</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

and there is a jQuery code like this:

```
$("tr#info").click(function() {        // function_tr
  $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
});

$("tr#info td").click(function() {     // function_td
  $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
});
```

When I click on the `td`, `function_td` works fine but `function_tr` also works.
How to do prevent `function_tr`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$("tr#info td").click(function(e){     //function_td
  $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$("tr#info td").click(function(e){     //function_td
  $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/