# VB.NET HTML Table - onclick

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In the below html table on cell click i want the row to change colour.When i tried to change colour on click,then toggle_visibility('tbl1') is not working.

```
 <tr style ="cursor: pointer;" tr bgcolor="#4682B4"></style>   <td width="5%" class="style2" onclick="toggle_visibility('tbl1');"></td>
```

I can ask this in a simple manner,ie

in this code only one is working.If i remove toggle_visibility then background colour is working and vice versa.

Thanks i have solved the issue.

Comment: Where's the table? Can you post your code?

Comment: I'd suggest using JQuery for this. See this post (and other here) for more info. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290701/jquery-click-on-table-cell-event   Also, you should post your code for "toggle_visibility" to get more help.

Comment: Ia m not sure where to place the code of colour change in onclick.

Comment: on click of <td> i want that cell/row to change it colour.

Comment: I can ask this in a simple manner,ie


<td onclick= "toggle_visibility('tbl1');" "this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red'";"></td>

in this code only one is working.If i remove toggle_visibility then background colour is working and vice versa.