# Using HTML table cells as input

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm pretty new with php, HTML, and mysql. This is the first time I've used HTML tables.

I've populated an HTML table with rows from a MySQL table. I want this table to function as a menu, where the user can click on a cell with the appropriate date. Then, that date would be passed as a session variable to pull more information from the corresponding row in the MySQL table using another .php file.

Question: How do I get the date from the table cell that was clicked out as a variable?

Below is my table so far:

```
  <div div style="height:200px;width:350px;overflow:auto;">  
  <table class="table">   
      <tr>          
          </tr>   
          <?php 
            echo "<tbody>";
             while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>". $result['iso_date'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>". $result['lab_monitor'] . "</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";  
          ?>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: have a look at ajax.

Comment: Have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290701/jquery-click-on-table-cell-event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Jquery and Ajax

**HTML**

```
<td data-id='".$result['iso_date']."'>
    <button class='date-button'>Reserve Book</button>
</td>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
$('.date-button').click(function(){

    var iso_date = $(this).parent().data('id');

    $.ajax
    ({ 
        url: 'otherPhp.php',
        data: {"iso_date": iso_date},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(result)
        {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Make sure to import Jquery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

**Or you can do something like this without javascript :**

```
echo "<td><a href='whatEverURL.php?myParameter=".$result['iso_date']."'>". $result['iso_date'] . "</a></td>";
```

Then you can read URL parameter by using `$_GET['myParameter']` and assign inside same php file.

Comment: That was the answer. I used that final echo statement and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the help!

Comment: np :-) you are welcome